# Heavy upper arm/arm pit twisting with Rigify rig, any ideas how to fix?

Tags: armature, rigify

I have been working on a game for over a year and I am primarily a programmer so 3D software is very new to me. Early in the project to get things working I used Rigify in Blender to create a rig for my low poly character. I've since created 50+ animations using this rig and the more I work with the rig the more frustrating it becomes due to strange twists I just have no idea how to solve. With so many animations already made I am reluctant to completely re-rig in fear I'll lose all of the animations. I am not sure if this is a rig issue or topology or both. As you can see when the character's arms are raised I get an awful twist around the shoulder.

What would be the best course of action to try fix this? Thank you!

[image: Front twist with arms up]

[image: Back twist with arms up]

[image]

[[image]

[image: full rig]

[image]

Comment: It looks like some strange weight paints, you might need to edit them a bit.